# What are "Good / Correct things" to a Buddhist to do?

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, sutras

We know there are good and bad things in the world,now that is general knowledge.But our version of right and worlds version of it seems to go against each other,

So my question is what are the actual good things as opposed to worlds view of it?

Comment: What do you mean by "our version of right and worlds version of it seems to go against each other"? Can you give an example? Who is "we"?

Comment: "We" means Buddhists, "our version of right and worlds version of it seems to go against each other" means the experience you gain when you start the path. (Like the a dying person living off a Life support system. For the world mercy killing is a good choice but we are against it.) @michau

Answer (score 2):

Simply do what is *really* beneficial you and / or others.

Answer (score 1):

The **Noble Eightfold Path** tells us the "good" and "correct" things to do, in an overall way.

> 1. Right view
> 2. Right intention
> 3. Right speech
> 4. Right action
> 5. Right livelihood
> 6. Right effort
> 7. Right mindfulness
> 8. Right concentration